# Iframe is not working on my website while working on local

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe, embed

```
<iframe class="metaframe rptss" src="//fileru.net/iframe.php?v=089d20963d577068d193e23819b04652" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Hello people,

I really need help. So the iframe code you see above is working perfectly on my localhost server and i can watch it without problem but when i use this same embed link on my real server it doesn't work, it just shows a black screen instead of playing button. I am trying to figure it out for days but i couldn't find a solution. I got the embed link from this website(https://720p-izle.com/izle/altyazi/modo-aviao.html) and it works there perfectly as well but it doesn't work when i add it to my own website while working on localhost.

**NOTE:** You might see "this video is removed because of copyright(in Turkish)", when you open the embed link. It is because this embed link just opening it in certain IP(Turkish IP) as i guess. So this embed links is working for me but only problem is that i can see video when i click, when i add my localhost or when i go to the website where i took the link from but it doesn't work when i added it to my own website.

I was trying and searching so many things but i couldn't figure it out. So i also add #document as well and it gives some clue about the solution when i look but i don't have enough knowledge to understand it and fix the problem.

Another thing is that i also use some  tools like(https://www.w3schools.com/tryit/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_default) to see if problem is just because of my hosting and video is also not working on this tool as well.

I tried small things as well such as adding https://fileru...... or similar things and change iframe code but still it doesn't work. As i say before i saw some information about video working on documentation but i don't have enough coding knowledge to understand it.

Please help me because i am searching for the solution for days and i couldn't find anything.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="tr"><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <title>Video Player</title>
    <meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer">    <script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script><script>
        function checkScreen() {
            if (window.outerHeight > 1 && window.outerWidth > 1) {
                if (window.outerHeight < 200 && window.outerWidth < 300) {
                    window.location.href = 'about:blank';
                }
            } else {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    checkScreen();
                }, 2);
            }
        }
        checkScreen();
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jwplayer.com/libraries/wr6i4gal.js"></script>
    </head>

<body>
    <div id="Player"></div>
    <div id="icon-forward-desktop" class="jw-icon jw-icon-inline jw-button-color jw-reset jw-icon-rewind" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-label="10 Saniye İleri Sar">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="jw-svg-icon jw-svg-icon-rewind" viewBox="0 0 240 240" focusable="false">
            <path d="M193.14,131.08a21.57,21.57,0,0,0-17.7-10.6,21.58,21.58,0,0,0-17.7,10.6,44.77,44.77,0,0,0,0,46.3,21.63,21.63,0,0,0,17.7,10.6,21.61,21.61,0,0,0,17.7-10.6A44.77,44.77,0,0,0,193.14,131.08Zm-17.7,47.2c-7.8,0-14.4-11-14.4-24.1s6.6-24.1,14.4-24.1,14.4,11,14.4,24.1S183.34,178.28,175.44,178.28ZM132,188V137l-4.8,4.8-6.8-6.8,13-13a4.8,4.8,0,0,1,8.2,3.4v62.7ZM30.89,52.88H161V33.58c0-5.3,3.6-7.2,8-4.3l41.8,27.9a5.8,5.8,0,0,1,2.7,2.7,6,6,0,0,1-2.7,8L169,95.78c-4.4,2.9-8,1-8-4.3V72.18H45.29v96.4h48.2v19.3H30.79a4.88,4.88,0,0,1-4.8-4.8V57.78A5,5,0,0,1,30.89,52.88Z"></path>
        </svg>
        <div class="jw-reset-text jw-tooltip jw-tooltip-rewind" dir="auto">
            <div class="jw-text">10 Saniye İleri Sar</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="icon-forward-mobile" class="jw-display-icon-container jw-display-icon-rewind jw-reset">
        <div class="jw-icon jw-icon-rewind jw-button-color jw-reset" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-label="10 Saniye İleri Sar">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="jw-svg-icon jw-svg-icon-rewind" viewBox="0 0 240 240" focusable="false">
                <path d="M193.14,131.08a21.57,21.57,0,0,0-17.7-10.6,21.58,21.58,0,0,0-17.7,10.6,44.77,44.77,0,0,0,0,46.3,21.63,21.63,0,0,0,17.7,10.6,21.61,21.61,0,0,0,17.7-10.6A44.77,44.77,0,0,0,193.14,131.08Zm-17.7,47.2c-7.8,0-14.4-11-14.4-24.1s6.6-24.1,14.4-24.1,14.4,11,14.4,24.1S183.34,178.28,175.44,178.28ZM132,188V137l-4.8,4.8-6.8-6.8,13-13a4.8,4.8,0,0,1,8.2,3.4v62.7ZM30.89,52.88H161V33.58c0-5.3,3.6-7.2,8-4.3l41.8,27.9a5.8,5.8,0,0,1,2.7,2.7,6,6,0,0,1-2.7,8L169,95.78c-4.4,2.9-8,1-8-4.3V72.18H45.29v96.4h48.2v19.3H30.79a4.88,4.88,0,0,1-4.8-4.8V57.78A5,5,0,0,1,30.89,52.88Z"></path>
            </svg></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var id = '181735092eb53d9ac628d04c735abf67';
                    var Playlist = false;

        var PlayerSettings = {
            width: '100%',
            primary: 'html5',
            autostart: false,
            cast: {},
            preload: 'auto',
            playlist: Playlist,
            renderCaptionsNatively: true,
            playbackRateControls: [0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2],
        };

        if (localStorage['position_' + id] > 30) {
            //PlayerSettings.preload = 'none';
        }

        function inIframe() {
            try {
                return window.self !== window.top;
            } catch (e) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        function UpdateQualityText() {
            var label = jwplayer().getQualityLevels()[jwplayer().getCurrentQuality()]['label'];
            if (label.length > 1) {
                $('#QualityText').show().html('Aktif Kalite: <b>' + label.replace('Auto', 'Otomatik') + '</b>');
            }
        };

        function setPlayerEvents(Player) {
            var Once = true;
            var Played = false;
            var Watched = false;
            Player.on('seek', function(a) {
                Once = false;
            });
            Player.on('play', function() {
                Played = true;
                if (Once) {
                    UpdateQualityText();
                    if (localStorage['position_' + id] > 30) {
                        jwplayer().seek(localStorage['position_' + id] - 5);
                    }
                    Once = false;
                }
            });
            var sendTime = 0;
            Player.on('time', function() {
                localStorage.setItem('position_' + id, Player.getPosition())
                if (!Once) {
                    var timestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
                    if (timestamp > sendTime + 5) {
                        sendTime = timestamp;
                        window.parent.postMessage({
                            timeInfo: {
                                time: Player.getPosition(),
                                duration: Player.getDuration()
                            }
                        }, '*');
                    }
                }
                if (!Watched) {
                    var RemainTime = Player.getDuration() - Player.getPosition();
                    if (RemainTime > 1 && RemainTime < 60) {
                        Watched = true;
                        window.parent.postMessage('videoWatched', '*');
                    }
                }
            });
            Player.on('complete', function() {
                delete localStorage['position_' + id];
            });

            Player.on('displayClick', function() {
                                if ($('#QualityText').length == 0) {
                    var mo = new MutationObserver(function(m) {
                        if (!$('.jw-flag-user-inactive').length) {
                            $('#QualityText').show();
                        } else {
                            $('#QualityText').hide();
                        }
                    });
                    mo.observe(document.querySelector('.jwplayer'), {
                        attributes: true
                    });

                    $('.jw-media').prepend(
                        '<div id="QualityText" style="display:none; width:170px; height:30px; font: normal 16px arial; line-height:30px; text-align:right; color:#fff; background:#0000; position:absolute; top:20px; right:20px; z-index:5;"></div>'
                    );
                }
            });

            Player.on('ready', function() {
                $('#icon-forward-desktop').insertAfter('.jw-icon-rewind:eq(1)');
                $('#icon-forward-mobile').insertAfter('.jw-display-icon-display');
                $('.jw-display-icon-next').hide();

                $('#icon-forward-desktop, #icon-forward-mobile').click(function() {
                    jwplayer().seek(jwplayer().getPosition() + 10);
                });
            });

            Player.on('pause', function() {
                if (!puShown && popURL) {initPu();}            });

            Player.on('levelsChanged', function(e, a) {
                UpdateQualityText();
            });


            setInterval(function() {
                if (Played && Player.getQualityLevels()[Player.getCurrentQuality()]['label'] == 'Auto') {
                    var label = Player.getQualityLevels()[Player.getVisualQuality().level.index]['label'];
                    $('#QualityText').html(
                        'Aktif Kalite: <b>Otomatik <span style="font-weight:normal; font-size:11px; font-weight: 700; top:-3px; margin-left:2px; padding: 3px 5px 3px 5px; border-radius: 5px; background:#35c2ff; color:#000; position:relative;">' +
                        label + '</span></b>');
                }
            }, 1000);

                            Player.addButton(
                    'https://fileru-net.cdn.ampproject.org/i/s/fileru.net/misc/download.svg?2',
                    'Videoyu İndir',
                    function() {
                        var url =
                            '/download.php?v=089d20963d577068d193e23819b04652';
                        var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
                        win.focus();
                    },
                    'download'
                );
                    }
        var Trusted = false;
        if (inIframe() && !Trusted) {
            document.write('Videoyu oynatmaya yetkiniz yok.');
        } else {
                            var prefetchPoster = new Image();
                prefetchPoster.src = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280/9OaIWmWI7Ph3jqj235zQIrh5yVd.jpg';

                var Expire = false;
                $.getJSON('/source.php?h=7715d59a058cef05555c295105624519a77a08c27c664c50d00001a6be526a0e032f03061c37ecd74137f5d6adb024788ef3d365950f81392ad735d723cf83cbba3b94172f8b40f6c030d0eac4bb10b434f7b53733e54a7c02b7810bcc862eca7b3df51f47f3af15e32b0ca86ecf910c6c80fb39b12c69815a85ce7faea88c0182709447c0ba8d1c208f2dc1ca8c4ad5', function(Response) {
                    PlayerSettings.image = prefetchPoster.src;
                    PlayerSettings.sources = Response.sources;
                    PlayerSettings.tracks = [];
                    Expire = Response.expire;
                    var Player = jwplayer('Player').setup(PlayerSettings);
                    setPlayerEvents(Player);

                    setInterval(function() {
                        var time = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
                        if (Expire != false && time > Expire) {
                            var tmpExpire = Expire;
                            Expire = false;
                            $.getJSON('/source.php?h=7715d59a058cef05555c295105624519a77a08c27c664c50d00001a6be526a0e032f03061c37ecd74137f5d6adb024788ef3d365950f81392ad735d723cf83cbba3b94172f8b40f6c030d0eac4bb10b434f7b53733e54a7c02b7810bcc862eca7b3df51f47f3af15e32b0ca86ecf910c6c80fb39b12c69815a85ce7faea88c0182709447c0ba8d1c208f2dc1ca8c4ad5&e=' + tmpExpire, function(Response) {
                                var LastPosition = Player.getPosition();
                                var LastState = Player.getState();
                                Expire = Response.expire;
                                PlayerSettings.sources = Response.sources;
                                Player.load(PlayerSettings);
                                jwplayer().seek(LastPosition);
                                if (LastState == 'playing') {
                                    Player.play();
                                } else {
                                    Player.pause();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }, 1000);


                });

                    }

        function receiveMessage(event) {
            var data = event.data;
            if ('playerSeek' in data) {
                jwplayer().seek(data['playerSeek']);
            }
        }
        window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

            </script>Videoyu oynatmaya yetkiniz yok.
    <script>
        var popURL = "https://720p-izle.com/detay/fast-furious-presents-hobbs-shaww/";            var puShown = false;

            function doOpen(url) {
                if (puShown == true) {
                    return true;
                }
                win = window.open(url, 'yenipencere', 'menubar=0,resizable=1,width=1,height=1');
                win.moveTo(150000, 150000);
                if (win) {
                    win.blur();
                    puShown = true;
                }
                return win;
            }

            function setCookie(cname, cvalue, extime) {
                var d = new Date();
                d.setTime(d.getTime() + extime);
                var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
                document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
            }

            function getCookie(cname) {
                var name = cname + "=";
                var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
                var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
                for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                    var c = ca[i];
                    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                        c = c.substring(1);
                    }
                    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                        return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
                    }
                }
                return "";
            }

            function initPu() {
                if (document.attachEvent) {
                    document.attachEvent('onclick', checkTarget);
                } else if (document.addEventListener) {
                    document.addEventListener('click', checkTarget, false);
                }
            }

            function checkTarget(e) {
                if (!getCookie('popunderPause')) {
                    var e = e || window.event;
                    var win = doOpen(popURL);
                    setCookie('popunderPause', 1, 1 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
                }
            }
            </script>
    <script async="" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-125574692-2"></script>
    <script>
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

        function gtag() {
            dataLayer.push(arguments);
        }
        gtag('js', new Date());
        gtag('config', 'UA-125574692-2');
    </script>
    <script>
            </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            background: #000;
        }

        #Player {
            position: fixed;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100% !important;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            z-index: 10
        }

        .jw-rightclick {
            display: none !important
        }

        .jw-settings-menu {
            width: 135px !important;
        }

        .jw-breakpoint-7 .jw-settings-menu,
        .jw-breakpoint-6 .jw-settings-menu,
        .jw-breakpoint-5 .jw-settings-menu,
        .jw-breakpoint-4 .jw-settings-menu,
        .jw-breakpoint-3 .jw-settings-menu {
            max-height: 220px !important;
            height: 220px !important;
        }

        .jw-settings-content-item {
            font-size: 15px
        }

        .jw-settings-content-item.jw-settings-item-active {
            color: #35c2ff
        }

        .jw-text-elapsed,
        .jw-text-duration {
            font-size: 15px
        }

        .jw-slider-horizontal .jw-slider-container {
            height: 10px
        }

        .jw-knob {
            height: 16px;
            width: 16px
        }
    </style>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/normalize.css@8.0.1/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="misc/style.css?3" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">



</body></html>
```

Comment: Where in the `<iframe>` in your main code?

Comment: @Bored  Please check browse console .

Comment: Also, is this the same as your [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60249986/embed-link-is-working-on-localhost-but-not-on-real-server) question? If so, I would advise you delete your other question.

Comment: Hello i checked my console and it says that =                                    
JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
(index):1 A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://fileru.net/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.

Comment: Hello `<iframe>` is on this xpath = `/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/iframe`

Comment: Where is your "real server" located ? sounds like you may have firewall/web server issues if this works on your local machine but not when deployed?

Comment: Yes it works on local but not working on my server when i deployed as you say. My server is in Netherland. I also thought same thing and i was contacting the company where i took the server but they couldn't help as well.

Comment: Do you have SSL certificate (https) installed on your domain (Is your domain showing the padlock sign)?

Comment: Yes i have SSL certificate on my domain and shows the padlock sign.